# How do i make selection bold in the NStextview?

Tags: cocoa, fonts, nstextview, bold

Use the setFont: range: ? but what i want to do here is only to make the selection bold as the selection may have different font attribute,so,anyone can tell that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* text = [textView textStorage];
[text applyFontTraits:NSBoldFontMask range:NSMakeRange(0,[text length])];
```

where the range is the range of text you want to make bold.

Comment: Thx for reply,though i get it done with code below,[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] addFontTrait:sender];

Answer (score 0):

You could also simulate the CMD+B key press like so:

```
// Simulates CMD+B
    CGEventSourceRef src =
    CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);

    CGEventRef cmdd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x38, true);
    CGEventRef cmdu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x38, false);
    // Key codess for the (B) key
    CGEventRef Bd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x0b, true);
    CGEventRef Bu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x0b, false);

    CGEventSetFlags(Bd, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
    CGEventSetFlags(Bu, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);

    CGEventTapLocation loc = kCGHIDEventTap; 
    CGEventPost(loc, cmdd);
    CGEventPost(loc, Bd);
    CGEventPost(loc, Bu);
    CGEventPost(loc, cmdu);

    CFRelease(cmdd);
    CFRelease(cmdu);
    CFRelease(Bd);
    CFRelease(Bu);
    CFRelease(src);
```